# Using Data Validation in Google Sheets to only allow numbers, commas and spaces

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am creating an input google sheet to accept just numbers, commas & spaces - examples listed below. - At a basic level, I just want to exclude the use of A-Z / a-z.

```
80092382
800
800,876
98672102,20192210
```

I would like it to exclude anything like:

```
Hey 01
987 blue
black 1 white
orange
```

I am getting stuck early on, where I'm trying to only allow text with only numbers in, or excluding anything with letters in.
I have tried the following lines of code within the RegexMatch formula but it either accepts lines with text, or rejects my numbers.

```
=RegexMatch(L5,"\d")
- This one rejects the numbers.
    
=RegexMatch(to_text(L5),"\d")
- This rejects only where there are no numbers in the cell - So 'Hey 01' is accepted.

=RegexMatch(to_text(L5),"^\d")
- Same issue, if the cell starts with a number '987 blue' then its accepted
```

I've attempted a few other ways, such as using the NOT function at the beginning & using other regular expressions. If anyone can point me in the right direction then that would be much appreciated.

[Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bz4ov4aRkz49TRKD0xFkA5chFscgiimu4jLxtoagCqQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try `REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(L5), "\d+(?:,\d+)*")`. If spaces are allowed anywhere, `"\s*\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*"`

Comment: @wiktor Thanks for the quick response. I get the same problem where cells with just words in are removed, but if I include a number in the cell, it is accepted.

Comment: Not sure I get it, look [here](https://regex101.com/r/EgxJv7/1).

Comment: Paul, did you check the regex demo at https://regex101.com/r/EgxJv7/1 and did you use `=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(L5), "\d+(?:,\d+)*")`  in Google Sheets document (not in any online tester)?

Comment: @wiktor Ive tried the tester and directly in the data validator tool in google sheets. I have created a test sheet to show my issues.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bz4ov4aRkz49TRKD0xFkA5chFscgiimu4jLxtoagCqQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(C2:C9), "^\d+(,\s*\d+)*$"), "Good", "Error"))`

Comment: @Wiktor That formula works as expected. Thanks for your help. Im going to test it further.

Comment: If my answer did not solve your issue please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(C2:C9), "^\d+(,\s*\d+)*$"), "Good", "Error"))
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(,\s*\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s*` - zero or whitespace
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the content with this type of regex:

`=arrayformula(if(regexmatch(to_text(A1:A),"([^\d.,])"),"Error",))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I did try this regular expression earlier to the same issue. Although the formula regexmatch worked as intended, putting the same formula in data validation, flips the responses.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bz4ov4aRkz49TRKD0xFkA5chFscgiimu4jLxtoagCqQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah, I think you may be better off using your helper column to tell you when the validation fails. What about changing the data validation criteria to be a Number greater than 0?